# Breadcrumb not inline

Tags: html, css

I have a code for breadcrumb I have styled it but not showing as expected any help please will help. Here are both my code and CSS style and the final output am getting

```css
.breadcrumb {
  font-size: var(--font-small);
  padding: 0 .5rem;
}

.breadcrumb ul .flexitem {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.breadcrumb li:not(:last-child)::after {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 .35rem;
  content: '/';
}

.breadcrump li:last-child {
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  color: var(--light-text-color);
}
```

```html
<div class="single-product">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="breadcrumb">
        <ul class="flexitem">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Novels</a></li>
          <li>The river and the source</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: My final output]

Comment: The code you posted doesn't produce the image

Comment: try to remove the space between ul and .flexitem

Comment: I have tried but still no changes at all

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are `.breadcrumb ul .flexitem` this should be `.breadcrumb ul.flexitem` since "flexitem" is a class on the ul and not a child of the ul-element.

```css
.breadcrumb {
  font-size: var(--font-small);
  padding: 0 .5rem;
}

.breadcrumb ul.flexitem {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.breadcrumb li:not(:last-child)::after {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 .35rem;
  content: '/';
}

.breadcrump li:last-child {
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  color: var(--light-text-color);
}
```

```html
<div class="single-product">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="breadcrumb">
        <ul class="flexitem">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Novels</a></li>
          <li>The river and the source</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```